# Unity - Set Pivot at Center of Two GameObects with C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, alignment, pivot, center

How set pivot position between two images (gameObejcts)?

Currently i have this:

[image]

I hope the following result:

[image]

How do I calculate the center of the objects contained within my GameObject called "PointsImages", to keep this on center of "Score-Image" gameObject?

See the video: https://youtu.be/wq0-lOOTd1w

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do the alignment at run-time or at the editor?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using this in conjunction with the Unity UI system (based on your screenshots), you should be able to use the [`RectTransform` component](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html) to get the information you need.

By default, the pivot of your transform will be at its position. With this information, we can just calculate the average of the two positions to get the average of their pivot points.

Here's a code snippet, though I'm only guessing at what you want since you didn't include any attempts (code not tested, unfortunately):

```cs
// In the editor, drag the corresponding elements into these public fields
public RectTransform imageTransform1;
public RectTransform imageTransform2;
public RectTransform numberTransform;

Update() {
    Vector2 averagePivot = (imageTransform1.anchoredPosition + imageTransform2.anchoredPosition) / 2;
    // Use this information as you will
    numberTransform.anchoredPosition = averagePivot;
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Serlite, but what is 'numberTransform' on scene?

Comment: @IgoR Oh, I just assumed you were trying to position some object using the average position, based on the note in your screenshot `...keep the number on center of gameObject "PointsImages"`, so I added `numberTransform` to hold the transform of the number. If this doesn't fit your purposes, then omit it and adapt the code to your implementation as needed.

Comment: I just need to put the pivot in the center of the objects and then change the X position 'PointsImages' to 0! So that it is centered. I would not want to mess around with any property of the Canvas. See my video please: https://youtu.be/wq0-lOOTd1w

Comment: @IgoR All right, I think I understand what you mean. Is it imperative that the pivot point be changed, or would it be enough to just reposition the parent element (without changing its pivot point)? (Are you planning on doing more stuff with the pivot later?)